# Can I challenge a character with a '-' ability to a duel?

Tags: legend-of-the-five-rings

The rules on having a '-' attribute only say that they are not able to participate in conflicts of that type. However, if a card that has "Political 1, Military -" is in a Political conflict, can I challenge that card to a Military duel, or is it not a valid target?

And if it is a valid target, what is its Military skill in this situation? Can it add any modifiers it gets from being Honored or from attachments for the duel score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/b3/b7/b3b74cee-5ea1-44f7-a459-466c3d7edc81/l5c01-rules_reference-v101.pdf), page 5, under "Dash (-)", the following bullet point is relevant (emphasis mine):

> - A character with a dash skill value **cannot** be a challenger or challengee in a duel of that skill type. (see D.2 on page 23)

So, no, the character you describe cannot participate in a military duel, either as the challengee or the challenger.

The bullet point immediately above it covers the case where such a character's skill value is needed by an effect and that value is a dash (which can happen), in which case the skill value will always be 0 at the time it is checked by the effect and cannot be modified.

Comment: This rules reference is great. Contains way more info than the actual rulebook in the box...

Comment: You probably were referencing the How to Play manual (https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/74/46/7446c964-613e-4c01-8902-199257c5d4af/l5c01_learntoplay_web.pdf), which does teach how the game is played but doesn't cover all of the rules. I'd be surprised if the Rules Reference _wasn't_ in the box, though page 3 of the how to play manual would suggest just that.